# Read Excel Data from S3 using Lambda

Tags: excel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
import xlrd
  resp = obj.get()
  lines = resp['Body'].read()
  book = xlrd.open_workbook(lines)
  sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
```

I'm trying to read excel file in S3 bucket using a lambda function. While I try to run this code it throws back an exception:

> "embedded null byte"

I'm still learning. Can somebody please help me with where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `xlrd` but I don't immediately see any options to pass the body of a CSV/XLSX file, or to stream content to it.

You may need to download the spreadsheet to the Lambda function's `/tmp` folder (max. space is 512MB) and then open it using `xlrd.open_workbook('/tmp/data.xlsx')`.

If it's larger than 512MB then you will need to get creative. For example, use a larger Lambda RAM size (say 1024MB), find a Python package that provides an in-memory file, and then populate that from an S3 object stream, then pass a virtual file to `xlrd.open_workbook()`.

Comment: Thank you for the response! That is exactly what I did. I have downloaded it to '/tmp' directory and then opened the book.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:
You just have to download the file to '/tmp' directory. Here is the minor modification:

```
resp = obj.get()
lines = resp['Body'].read()
with open('/tmp/'+ 'Import.xlsx','wb') as f:
     s3_client.download_file('tdx-in-bucket',key,'/tmp/'+ 'Import.xlsx')
     book = xlrd.open_workbook('/tmp/'+'Canada Import.xlsx')
     sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
```

Comment: While this might work, the code needs some changes. It's getting the S3 object unnecessarily, and it's opening /tmp/Import.xlsx unnecessarily.

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you very much for the help.